# Get Ip of Rapberry Pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, ip

I want to get the ip address of my raspberry pi(connected directly on my LAN port) using is mac (only from this mac) in C++.

I'm using a laptop Windows and I tried to use [GetAdaptersAddresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx), but I stuck in the part of cannot get the ip address from my Ethernet adapter and convert it to `unsigned long`.

Any Ideas how to do it?

Comment: Are you writing code that will run on the Raspberry Pi itself?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, running on my pc

Comment: If you're not on the same machine, the only way to get an IP from a MAC address is by looking in the ARP cache.

Comment: And that only works if you're on the same LAN as the target machine, and the two machines have communicated recently.

Comment: @Barmar The raspberry pi is connected directly to my PC

Comment: So look in the ARP cache. But this may be a Catch-22: if you don't know the IP, you can't send a message to the RPi to get it into the ARP cache.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `route -ne` in your pi. In the corner you will see ethernet and wlan, under gateway will be your ip adress.